# jQuery .load()-function doesn't reload element (Rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails Project, I am trying to alter an instance variable via JS in a controller response (create.js.erb) and then reload an HTML-Element that makes use of the instance variable. But it doesn't work. Is it possible? This is just an example.

I also want to display the newly created object. But as I don't seem to understand the mechanism of exchanging information between rails and JS, I wanted to keep it simple here.

vocabs-controller.rb

```
def new
  @user = current_user
  @vocab = @user.vocabs.build
  @vocabs = @user.vocabs.all
  @count = @vocabs.count
  .
  .
end 

def create
  @user = current_user
  @vocab = @user.vocabs.build(vocab_params)
  @count = @user.vocabs.count
  .
  .
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      redirect_to new_user_vocab_path(@user)
      flash[:success] = "Vocab created!"
    end
    format.js {render :layout=>false}
  end
    else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render 'vocabs/new'}
    format.js  
  end
end
```

new.html.erb (from here I make the call to the controllers create action)

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <%= form_for(@vocab, 
         url: user_vocabs_path(@user),
         method: :post, remote: true) do |f| %>
      .
      .
      .
      <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>  

    <h4> 
      <%= @count %> Vocabs in your collection
    </h4>
    <%= link_to "(Show)", "#", id: "show_link" %>
    <%= link_to "(Hide)", "#", id: "hide_link" %>

    <ul class='vocabs <%= @vocabs_class %>'>
      <% @vocabs.each do |vocab| %>
        <%= render vocab %> 
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <hr> 
    <%= link_to "Back", home_user_path(@user) %> 
</div>
.
.
```

create.js.erb

```
<% @count+=1 %>
$('h4').load();
```

The server recognizes that I made a JS request and also renders `create.js.erb` with 200 OK. But the .load() function doesn't seem to reload the h4-Element with the new data.

When I was trying to .load() the div-element that contains the formular fields, these also weren't updated. The text input was still visible.

Further question: Where can I debug the code in JS Controller responses? I can't find them neither in Chrome's dev tools nor in Rails's server output.

Comment: Pretty sure `load()` doesn't do anything since it doesn't have any parameters. Try using `html` instead. You can inject `erb` this way.

Comment: Isn't there a way to refresh an existing html-element without providing the code?

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, try

Add an id attribute to `h4`:

```
<h4 id="count-header">...</h4>
```

And in the `.erb.js` callback:

```
$('#count-header').text('<%= @count += 1 %> Vocabs in your collection');
```

Comment: This is exactly how I solved the problem. But I would like to find out how to  reload an HTML Element via Javacsript. With instance variable(s) altered in JS.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you wish to go about doing that. A general guidance is to use AJAX, capture a click event, for example, and fire a `GET` request to the controller. The framework does this for you when you set `remote: true` in your form.

Comment: Thx, for taking time to help.How would I specify the GET request to affect only one element? I never used AJAX, so far I was getting along with JQuery (which probably uses AJAX underneath). But especially if it's possible with AJAX there should be a function for jQuery then, right?

Comment: Yes, try `$.get()`. The API is intelligible and you can find documentation on their website. You want to point the `url` parameter to a controller and return a JSON.